# Change archive page and taxanomy slug with rewrite rule

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a cpt with two taxanomies. I want to the cpt archive link and add rewrite url such that I can add the taxanomy in the link with the archive name.

For example I have cpt name "staff" and two taxonomies with "location" and "industry". On the cpt (staff) archive page I have a dropdown for these taxanomies. If the user select on any taxanomy then the link should be mysite.com/staff/location or mysite.com/staff/industry.

Any ideas?

I tried adding the below rewrite rule.

```
function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
 
    $new_rules = array(
        'staff/(location|industry)/(.+?)/(location|indudtry)/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=staff&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'staff/(location|industry)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=staff&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules', 99 );
```

I want something similar to shown here  https://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/
but have my final url like
[www.example.com/events/nsw/web/](http://www.example.com/events/nsw/web/) instead of
[www.example.com/events/location/nsw/industry/web/](http://www.example.com/events/location/nsw/industry/web/)

Comment: See the `rewrite` parameter for the taxonomy, there's an [example here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#div-comment-2274)

Comment: Thanks that did helped! But still it isn't perfect on how I want

Comment: Please edit your original question with what you tried, what you expected for results, and what you received. Also, make sure to flush your permalinks whenever you make a change to rewrites.

Comment: I have edited the questions

Comment: My comment earlier was about updating the `rewrite` parameter for the register function. Pass it a slug value of `staff/location`